# Always -bash: gomobile: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, gomobile

I have installed gomobile at

```
/Users/GaryChan/go/bin/gomobile
```

and my project is

```
/Users/GaryChan/go/src/abc.com/project
```

When I try to run building android SDK at

```
/Users/GaryChan/go/src/abc.com/project/sdk
```

and run :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/GaryChan/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/


gomobile bind -target=android  abc.com/project/sdk
```

I go install go and go mobile but to no avail.
When I execute gomobile at My Mac Terminal, the cmd always prompt -bash: gomobile: command not found

Then I cannot export the SDK. What should I do ?

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile

Updates :

Go Version is : 
go version go1.11.1 darwin/amd64

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure `/Users/GaryChan/go/bin/` is in your `$PATH`. If it's not, edit your bash profile to add it. Your profile is a file in your home directory named either `.profile` or `.bash_profile`. It should contain a line like this:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/GaryChan/go/bin/"
```

Make this change, then close your Terminal window and open a new one, and you should be able to type `gomobile` to launch it.

Comment: I have to type evert time export PATH before proceeding SDK generation. Shall there has a permanent method to set this config ?

Comment: If you save this in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` file inside your home folder, it should run every time you open a new Terminal window.

Comment: Hi, How do I do this on github action using ubuntu? Any idea