# How to install gomobile properly on Windows?

Tags: go, gomobile

I'm on Windows 10, with go 1.16.7 windows/amd64 installed. Already defined **GOPATH** to
`C:\Users\anta40\Codes\Go`.

While in **GOPATH**, I ran these 2 commands:

```
go env -w GO111MODULE=auto
go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile
```

OK now let's run `gomobile`

> 'gomobile' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Hmm.. what's missing here?

Comment: Have you included `C:\Users\anta40\Codes\Go\bin` in your PATH?

Comment: @OlegButuzov Ah forgot to add that into %PATH%. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to include `~/go/bin` in your path variables.

A similar question was answered from [Always -bash: gomobile: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53245909/5671180), but you'll want to implement the answer on Windows by (setting the Path and environment variables](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)